# Failed to @Html.DropDownList()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I did check all issues about that but I couldn't figure out how to solve it. I need to your help guys.

Here is my code about dropdownlist. When I post the page I got the error message which I mentioned above. ERROR:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_ikconokc.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I want to use 2 models in 1 view. All works well except @Html.DropDownList. In View:

```
@model Tuple<Models.Framework.Drink, Models.Framework.Drinks_Category>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.Id_category, "Id_category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_category", new SelectList( Model.Item2.Id_category.ToList()), new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Id_category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried the following code but still get error:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id_category", new SelectList( Model.Item2.Id_category, "Value", "Text", Model.Item2), new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Table "Drink" is associated with table "Drinks_Category" with key Id_category. I want to use 2 models in 1 view. Please help me!

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: oh, sorry, this is : An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_ikconokc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: why not use viewmodel instead of tuple?

Comment: Please show us the controller action, wich is retuning that view, and the definition of the Models.Framework.Drinks_Category class.

Comment: thanks everyone!! @Konstantin Dinev solved the problem for me :)

Comment: You cannot use a `Tuple` for binding form controls (a `Tuple` has no default constructor, there for cannot be initialized by the `DefaultModelBinder` in the POST method). Use view models.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Models.Framework.Drinks_Category` is of type `IEnumerable`. Then what you should bind the DropDownList to is all of the `Drinks_Category` and pass what the value and text properties are:

```
@Html.DropDownList(tuple => tuple.Item2.Id_category, 
                   new SelectList( Model.Item2, "Id_category", "TextKey" ),
                   new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: Thank you But It does not work and still bugs: CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Models.Framework.Drinks_Category' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: As I said, I assumed it was an `IEnumerable`. What is the type of the `Drinks_Category` and can you call `ToList()` on it?

Comment: btw, how to convert List to IEnumerable in this code?, because "Models.Framework.Drinks_Category" is a List

Comment: Just try changing the first argument of the dropdownlist to "Id_category" to check if that will make the dropdownlist render.

Comment: no i can't  call ToList() on it  :'(

Comment: yes, i use  "Id_category" but its not work, and In the "Framework" folder is "BBDbContext.edmx", in it is "partial class Drinks_Category", is it error ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Change your controller to instead return a `List<Models.Framework.Drinks_Category>` as second item, because it seems to me like you're returning only one category in your model.